# Use of conditions to compute rows in Matrices

Tags: r

I have the following list object pgo_computation

```
pgo_computation
$tab_frpgo01_03_id
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
 [1,]  61197.50  50.83127  68.62763  45.61025   NA
 [2,]  53069.96  44.58885  70.92915  49.70095   NA
 [3,]  52915.62  41.43472  67.48709  52.36556   NA
 [4,]  48079.70  38.98638  69.93071  54.18271   NA
 [5,]  43663.61  36.62010  71.85329  56.07181   NA
 [6,]  44779.24  37.41887  65.12148  57.55446   NA
 [7,]  58961.00  49.45512  63.20634  58.65441   NA
 [8,]  68481.37  58.12665  64.47691  60.36152   NA
 [9,]  69754.89  60.43517  70.32266  62.54470   NA
[10,]  71436.86  58.64501  73.85853  64.88341   NA
[11,]  86556.53  69.99052  74.39722  67.25120   NA
[12,]  77780.34  69.04796  71.73626  69.22237   NA
[13,]  84344.09  74.45551  71.98332  70.68963   NA
[14,]  75206.94  70.09172  74.36378  72.20682   NA
[15,]  81362.46  72.20754  74.46316  73.71524   NA
[16,]  94262.73  81.13488  75.51454  75.34195   NA
[17,]  93415.79  80.27772  81.70116  76.46221   NA
[18,]  83356.23  71.12747  78.35197  77.37070   NA
[19,]  83891.89  70.60782  74.36657  77.64845   NA
[20,]  79555.75  67.58067  70.48241  78.83179   NA
[21,]  69952.24  59.90915  71.00253  80.80679   NA
[22,]  69371.77  59.04403  73.73129  82.18598   NA
[23,]  72813.47  62.74812  70.69789  83.17191   NA
[24,]  82077.88  76.07756  76.36066  84.95746   NA
[25,]  92931.28  85.04223  84.56366  87.45263   NA
[26,]  92845.21  86.98376  81.66493  90.57314   NA
[27,]  90899.11  90.00267  82.25471  93.47729   NA
[28,] 107746.64 100.32086  95.73597  96.06590   NA
[29,] 117741.81 110.17729 106.44017  99.08321   NA
[30,] 103889.66 103.27104  92.87811  98.25567   NA
[31,] 106385.91 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   NA
[32,] 119215.73 107.03833 120.59851 102.85797   NA
[33,] 108805.99 100.19533 125.82197 104.57031   NA
[34,] 102515.97 103.82839 128.09005 105.87292   NA
[35,] 110117.33 103.68537 127.18914 107.46275   NA
[36,]  94965.44  86.45841 115.17443 107.26643   NA
[37,]        NA  86.28260        NA 108.05543   NA
[38,]        NA  83.92894        NA 109.89962   NA
[39,]        NA  82.29632        NA 111.50721   NA
[40,]        NA  91.53973        NA 113.60008   NA
[41,]        NA 101.55865        NA 116.10783   NA
[42,]        NA 107.37999        NA 118.68726   NA
[43,]        NA 111.63570        NA 121.31223   NA
[44,]        NA 115.14157        NA 123.97757   NA
[45,]        NA 118.34679        NA 126.64159   NA
[46,]        NA 121.27528        NA 129.30434   NA
[47,]        NA 123.97783        NA 131.99454   NA
[48,]        NA 126.72214        NA 134.74379   NA
[49,]        NA 129.39579        NA 137.63494   NA
[50,]        NA 131.99770        NA 140.66371   NA
[51,]        NA 134.63692        NA 143.76488   NA
[52,]        NA 137.32613        NA 146.95503   NA
[53,]        NA 140.07149        NA 150.22311   NA
[54,]        NA 142.89485        NA 153.55776   NA
[55,]        NA 145.74041        NA 156.97532   NA
[56,]        NA 148.64303        NA 160.46257   NA
[57,]        NA 151.59553        NA 164.05430   NA

$tab_frpgo05_id
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 606.611  50.83127  62.42483  45.61025   NA
 [2,] 541.982  44.58885  67.51353  49.70095   NA
 [3,] 488.142  41.43472  70.45975  52.36556   NA
 [4,] 447.717  38.98638  66.65260  54.18271   NA
 [5,] 396.602  36.62010  66.45550  56.07181   NA
 [6,] 403.575  37.41887  66.03600  57.55446   NA
 [7,] 484.709  49.45512  62.34575  58.65441   NA
 [8,] 528.268  58.12665  59.35909  60.36152   NA
 [9,] 482.730  60.43517  56.06016  62.54470   NA
[10,] 453.475  58.64501  55.74644  64.88341   NA
[11,] 501.214  69.99052  55.81720  67.25120   NA
[12,] 481.897  69.04796  55.54264  69.22237   NA
[13,] 501.274  74.45551  54.46242  70.68963   NA
[14,] 429.002  70.09172  50.81890  72.20682   NA
[15,] 435.653  72.20754  50.64076  73.71524   NA
[16,] 464.742  81.13488  51.75018  75.34195   NA
[17,] 434.252  80.27772  50.24811  76.46221   NA
[18,] 223.274  71.12747  49.02389  77.37070   NA
[19,] 262.703  70.60782  49.17672  77.64845   NA
[20,] 151.623  67.58067  48.20985  78.83179   NA
[21,] 202.097  59.90915  49.03256  80.80679   NA
[22,] 200.542  59.04403  50.64192  82.18598   NA
[23,] 187.955  62.74812  52.70286  83.17191   NA
[24,] 154.251  76.07756  53.26376  84.95746   NA
[25,] 148.210  85.04223  57.50246  87.45263   NA
[26,] 247.455  86.98376  66.43959  90.57314   NA
[27,] 385.576  90.00267  71.23184  93.47729   NA
[28,] 380.786 100.32086  74.85468  96.06590   NA
[29,] 292.484 110.17729  88.50022  99.08321   NA
[30,] 221.454 103.27104  93.07073  98.25567   NA
[31,] 208.111 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   NA
[32,] 239.235 107.03833 109.18799 102.85797   NA
[33,] 264.751 100.19533 108.66621 104.57031   NA
[34,] 322.127 103.82839 104.11996 105.87292   NA
[35,] 318.313 103.68537  99.98200 107.46275   NA
[36,] 194.482  86.45841  97.63002 107.26643   NA
[37,]      NA  86.28260        NA 108.05543   NA
[38,]      NA  83.92894        NA 109.89962   NA
[39,]      NA  82.29632        NA 111.50721   NA
[40,]      NA  91.53973        NA 113.60008   NA
[41,]      NA 101.55865        NA 116.10783   NA
[42,]      NA 107.37999        NA 118.68726   NA
[43,]      NA 111.63570        NA 121.31223   NA
[44,]      NA 115.14157        NA 123.97757   NA
[45,]      NA 118.34679        NA 126.64159   NA
[46,]      NA 121.27528        NA 129.30434   NA
[47,]      NA 123.97783        NA 131.99454   NA
[48,]      NA 126.72214        NA 134.74379   NA
[49,]      NA 129.39579        NA 137.63494   NA
[50,]      NA 131.99770        NA 140.66371   NA
[51,]      NA 134.63692        NA 143.76488   NA
[52,]      NA 137.32613        NA 146.95503   NA
[53,]      NA 140.07149        NA 150.22311   NA
[54,]      NA 142.89485        NA 153.55776   NA
[55,]      NA 145.74041        NA 156.97532   NA
[56,]      NA 148.64303        NA 160.46257   NA
[57,]      NA 151.59553        NA 164.05430   NA

$tab_uspgo01_03_id
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 162759  45.61025  68.62763  45.61025   NA
 [2,] 178744  49.70095  70.92915  49.70095   NA
 [3,] 171164  52.36556  67.48709  52.36556   NA
 [4,] 156225  54.18271  69.93071  54.18271   NA
 [5,] 181960  56.07181  71.85329  56.07181   NA
 [6,] 172507  57.55446  65.12148  57.55446   NA
 [7,] 165704  58.65441  63.20634  58.65441   NA
 [8,] 175097  60.36152  64.47691  60.36152   NA
 [9,] 183236  62.54470  70.32266  62.54470   NA
[10,] 201975  64.88341  73.85853  64.88341   NA
[11,] 211193  67.25120  74.39722  67.25120   NA
[12,] 205421  69.22237  71.73626  69.22237   NA
[13,] 217009  70.68963  71.98332  70.68963   NA
[14,] 218591  72.20682  74.36378  72.20682   NA
[15,] 237711  73.71524  74.46316  73.71524   NA
[16,] 232653  75.34195  75.51454  75.34195   NA
[17,] 255595  76.46221  81.70116  76.46221   NA
[18,] 257791  77.37070  78.35197  77.37070   NA
[19,] 249705  77.64845  74.36657  77.64845   NA
[20,] 245248  78.83179  70.48241  78.83179   NA
[21,] 243533  80.80679  71.00253  80.80679   NA
[22,] 251233  82.18598  73.73129  82.18598   NA
[23,] 241336  83.17191  70.69789  83.17191   NA
[24,] 268152  84.95746  76.36066  84.95746   NA
[25,] 307154  87.45263  84.56366  87.45263   NA
[26,] 299633  90.57314  81.66493  90.57314   NA
[27,] 303499  93.47729  82.25471  93.47729   NA
[28,] 346942  96.06590  95.73597  96.06590   NA
[29,] 380539  99.08321 106.44017  99.08321   NA
[30,] 341925  98.25567  92.87811  98.25567   NA
[31,] 372752 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   NA
[32,] 434661 102.85797 120.59851 102.85797   NA
[33,] 447301 104.57031 125.82197 104.57031   NA
[34,] 481151 105.87292 128.09005 105.87292   NA
[35,] 492012 107.46275 127.18914 107.46275   NA
[36,] 446731 107.26643 115.17443 107.26643   NA
[37,] 421469 108.05543        NA 108.05543   NA
[38,]     NA 109.89962        NA 109.89962   NA
[39,]     NA 111.50721        NA 111.50721   NA
[40,]     NA 113.60008        NA 113.60008   NA
[41,]     NA 116.10783        NA 116.10783   NA
[42,]     NA 118.68726        NA 118.68726   NA
[43,]     NA 121.31223        NA 121.31223   NA
[44,]     NA 123.97757        NA 123.97757   NA
[45,]     NA 126.64159        NA 126.64159   NA
[46,]     NA 129.30434        NA 129.30434   NA
[47,]     NA 131.99454        NA 131.99454   NA
[48,]     NA 134.74379        NA 134.74379   NA
[49,]     NA 137.63494        NA 137.63494   NA
[50,]     NA 140.66371        NA 140.66371   NA
[51,]     NA 143.76488        NA 143.76488   NA
[52,]     NA 146.95503        NA 146.95503   NA
[53,]     NA 150.22311        NA 150.22311   NA
[54,]     NA 153.55776        NA 153.55776   NA
[55,]     NA 156.97532        NA 156.97532   NA
[56,]     NA 160.46257        NA 160.46257   NA
[57,]     NA 164.05430        NA 164.05430   NA

$tab_uspgo05_id
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 26216  45.61025  62.42483  45.61025   NA
 [2,] 28524  49.70095  67.51353  49.70095   NA
 [3,] 29438  52.36556  70.45975  52.36556   NA
 [4,] 24650  54.18271  66.65260  54.18271   NA
 [5,] 28549  56.07181  66.45550  56.07181   NA
 [6,] 27288  57.55446  66.03600  57.55446   NA
 [7,] 25440  58.65441  62.34575  58.65441   NA
 [8,] 25024  60.36152  59.35909  60.36152   NA
 [9,] 25964  62.54470  56.06016  62.54470   NA
[10,] 26034  64.88341  55.74644  64.88341   NA
[11,] 28111  67.25120  55.81720  67.25120   NA
[12,] 28141  69.22237  55.54264  69.22237   NA
[13,] 26373  70.68963  54.46242  70.68963   NA
[14,] 24615  72.20682  50.81890  72.20682   NA
[15,] 26564  73.71524  50.64076  73.71524   NA
[16,] 25744  75.34195  51.75018  75.34195   NA
[17,] 26169  76.46221  50.24811  76.46221   NA
[18,] 28327  77.37070  49.02389  77.37070   NA
[19,] 28511  77.64845  49.17672  77.64845   NA
[20,] 24763  78.83179  48.20985  78.83179   NA
[21,] 24635  80.80679  49.03256  80.80679   NA
[22,] 26483  82.18598  50.64192  82.18598   NA
[23,] 25535  83.17191  52.70286  83.17191   NA
[24,] 25983  84.95746  53.26376  84.95746   NA
[25,] 29986  87.45263  57.50246  87.45263   NA
[26,] 37549  90.57314  66.43959  90.57314   NA
[27,] 44497  93.47729  71.23184  93.47729   NA
[28,] 48185  96.06590  74.85468  96.06590   NA
[29,] 56937  99.08321  88.50022  99.08321   NA
[30,] 55827  98.25567  93.07073  98.25567   NA
[31,] 59100 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   NA
[32,] 71537 102.85797 109.18799 102.85797   NA
[33,] 68142 104.57031 108.66621 104.57031   NA
[34,] 61962 105.87292 104.11996 105.87292   NA
[35,] 61266 107.46275  99.98200 107.46275   NA
[36,] 51775 107.26643  97.63002 107.26643   NA
[37,] 32958 108.05543        NA 108.05543   NA
[38,]    NA 109.89962        NA 109.89962   NA
[39,]    NA 111.50721        NA 111.50721   NA
[40,]    NA 113.60008        NA 113.60008   NA
[41,]    NA 116.10783        NA 116.10783   NA
[42,]    NA 118.68726        NA 118.68726   NA
[43,]    NA 121.31223        NA 121.31223   NA
[44,]    NA 123.97757        NA 123.97757   NA
[45,]    NA 126.64159        NA 126.64159   NA
[46,]    NA 129.30434        NA 129.30434   NA
[47,]    NA 131.99454        NA 131.99454   NA
[48,]    NA 134.74379        NA 134.74379   NA
[49,]    NA 137.63494        NA 137.63494   NA
[50,]    NA 140.66371        NA 140.66371   NA
[51,]    NA 143.76488        NA 143.76488   NA
[52,]    NA 146.95503        NA 146.95503   NA
[53,]    NA 150.22311        NA 150.22311   NA
[54,]    NA 153.55776        NA 153.55776   NA
[55,]    NA 156.97532        NA 156.97532   NA
[56,]    NA 160.46257        NA 160.46257   NA
[57,]    NA 164.05430        NA 164.05430   NA

> pgo_computation
$tab_frpgo01_03_id
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
 [1,]  61197.50  50.83127  68.62763  45.61025   NA
 [2,]  53069.96  44.58885  70.92915  49.70095   NA
 [3,]  52915.62  41.43472  67.48709  52.36556   NA
 [4,]  48079.70  38.98638  69.93071  54.18271   NA
 [5,]  43663.61  36.62010  71.85329  56.07181   NA
 [6,]  44779.24  37.41887  65.12148  57.55446   NA
 [7,]  58961.00  49.45512  63.20634  58.65441   NA
 [8,]  68481.37  58.12665  64.47691  60.36152   NA
 [9,]  69754.89  60.43517  70.32266  62.54470   NA
[10,]  71436.86  58.64501  73.85853  64.88341   NA
[11,]  86556.53  69.99052  74.39722  67.25120   NA
[12,]  77780.34  69.04796  71.73626  69.22237   NA
[13,]  84344.09  74.45551  71.98332  70.68963   NA
[14,]  75206.94  70.09172  74.36378  72.20682   NA
[15,]  81362.46  72.20754  74.46316  73.71524   NA
[16,]  94262.73  81.13488  75.51454  75.34195   NA
[17,]  93415.79  80.27772  81.70116  76.46221   NA
[18,]  83356.23  71.12747  78.35197  77.37070   NA
[19,]  83891.89  70.60782  74.36657  77.64845   NA
[20,]  79555.75  67.58067  70.48241  78.83179   NA
[21,]  69952.24  59.90915  71.00253  80.80679   NA
[22,]  69371.77  59.04403  73.73129  82.18598   NA
[23,]  72813.47  62.74812  70.69789  83.17191   NA
[24,]  82077.88  76.07756  76.36066  84.95746   NA
[25,]  92931.28  85.04223  84.56366  87.45263   NA
[26,]  92845.21  86.98376  81.66493  90.57314   NA
[27,]  90899.11  90.00267  82.25471  93.47729   NA
[28,] 107746.64 100.32086  95.73597  96.06590   NA
[29,] 117741.81 110.17729 106.44017  99.08321   NA
[30,] 103889.66 103.27104  92.87811  98.25567   NA
[31,] 106385.91 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   NA
[32,] 119215.73 107.03833 120.59851 102.85797   NA
[33,] 108805.99 100.19533 125.82197 104.57031   NA
[34,] 102515.97 103.82839 128.09005 105.87292   NA
[35,] 110117.33 103.68537 127.18914 107.46275   NA
[36,]  94965.44  86.45841 115.17443 107.26643   NA
[37,]        NA  86.28260        NA 108.05543   NA
[38,]        NA  83.92894        NA 109.89962   NA
[39,]        NA  82.29632        NA 111.50721   NA
[40,]        NA  91.53973        NA 113.60008   NA
[41,]        NA 101.55865        NA 116.10783   NA
[42,]        NA 107.37999        NA 118.68726   NA
[43,]        NA 111.63570        NA 121.31223   NA
[44,]        NA 115.14157        NA 123.97757   NA
[45,]        NA 118.34679        NA 126.64159   NA
[46,]        NA 121.27528        NA 129.30434   NA
[47,]        NA 123.97783        NA 131.99454   NA
[48,]        NA 126.72214        NA 134.74379   NA
[49,]        NA 129.39579        NA 137.63494   NA
[50,]        NA 131.99770        NA 140.66371   NA
[51,]        NA 134.63692        NA 143.76488   NA
[52,]        NA 137.32613        NA 146.95503   NA
[53,]        NA 140.07149        NA 150.22311   NA
[54,]        NA 142.89485        NA 153.55776   NA
[55,]        NA 145.74041        NA 156.97532   NA
[56,]        NA 148.64303        NA 160.46257   NA
[57,]        NA 151.59553        NA 164.05430   NA

$tab_frpgo05_id
         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 606.611  50.83127  62.42483  45.61025   NA
 [2,] 541.982  44.58885  67.51353  49.70095   NA
 [3,] 488.142  41.43472  70.45975  52.36556   NA
 [4,] 447.717  38.98638  66.65260  54.18271   NA
 [5,] 396.602  36.62010  66.45550  56.07181   NA
 [6,] 403.575  37.41887  66.03600  57.55446   NA
 [7,] 484.709  49.45512  62.34575  58.65441   NA
 [8,] 528.268  58.12665  59.35909  60.36152   NA
 [9,] 482.730  60.43517  56.06016  62.54470   NA
[10,] 453.475  58.64501  55.74644  64.88341   NA
[11,] 501.214  69.99052  55.81720  67.25120   NA
[12,] 481.897  69.04796  55.54264  69.22237   NA
[13,] 501.274  74.45551  54.46242  70.68963   NA
[14,] 429.002  70.09172  50.81890  72.20682   NA
[15,] 435.653  72.20754  50.64076  73.71524   NA
[16,] 464.742  81.13488  51.75018  75.34195   NA
[17,] 434.252  80.27772  50.24811  76.46221   NA
[18,] 223.274  71.12747  49.02389  77.37070   NA
[19,] 262.703  70.60782  49.17672  77.64845   NA
[20,] 151.623  67.58067  48.20985  78.83179   NA
[21,] 202.097  59.90915  49.03256  80.80679   NA
[22,] 200.542  59.04403  50.64192  82.18598   NA
[23,] 187.955  62.74812  52.70286  83.17191   NA
[24,] 154.251  76.07756  53.26376  84.95746   NA
[25,] 148.210  85.04223  57.50246  87.45263   NA
[26,] 247.455  86.98376  66.43959  90.57314   NA
[27,] 385.576  90.00267  71.23184  93.47729   NA
[28,] 380.786 100.32086  74.85468  96.06590   NA
[29,] 292.484 110.17729  88.50022  99.08321   NA
[30,] 221.454 103.27104  93.07073  98.25567   NA
[31,] 208.111 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   NA
[32,] 239.235 107.03833 109.18799 102.85797   NA
[33,] 264.751 100.19533 108.66621 104.57031   NA
[34,] 322.127 103.82839 104.11996 105.87292   NA
[35,] 318.313 103.68537  99.98200 107.46275   NA
[36,] 194.482  86.45841  97.63002 107.26643   NA
[37,]      NA  86.28260        NA 108.05543   NA
[38,]      NA  83.92894        NA 109.89962   NA
[39,]      NA  82.29632        NA 111.50721   NA
[40,]      NA  91.53973        NA 113.60008   NA
[41,]      NA 101.55865        NA 116.10783   NA
[42,]      NA 107.37999        NA 118.68726   NA
[43,]      NA 111.63570        NA 121.31223   NA
[44,]      NA 115.14157        NA 123.97757   NA
[45,]      NA 118.34679        NA 126.64159   NA
[46,]      NA 121.27528        NA 129.30434   NA
[47,]      NA 123.97783        NA 131.99454   NA
[48,]      NA 126.72214        NA 134.74379   NA
[49,]      NA 129.39579        NA 137.63494   NA
[50,]      NA 131.99770        NA 140.66371   NA
[51,]      NA 134.63692        NA 143.76488   NA
[52,]      NA 137.32613        NA 146.95503   NA
[53,]      NA 140.07149        NA 150.22311   NA
[54,]      NA 142.89485        NA 153.55776   NA
[55,]      NA 145.74041        NA 156.97532   NA
[56,]      NA 148.64303        NA 160.46257   NA
[57,]      NA 151.59553        NA 164.05430   NA

$tab_uspgo01_03_id
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 162759  45.61025  68.62763  45.61025   NA
 [2,] 178744  49.70095  70.92915  49.70095   NA
 [3,] 171164  52.36556  67.48709  52.36556   NA
 [4,] 156225  54.18271  69.93071  54.18271   NA
 [5,] 181960  56.07181  71.85329  56.07181   NA
 [6,] 172507  57.55446  65.12148  57.55446   NA
 [7,] 165704  58.65441  63.20634  58.65441   NA
 [8,] 175097  60.36152  64.47691  60.36152   NA
 [9,] 183236  62.54470  70.32266  62.54470   NA
[10,] 201975  64.88341  73.85853  64.88341   NA
[11,] 211193  67.25120  74.39722  67.25120   NA
[12,] 205421  69.22237  71.73626  69.22237   NA
[13,] 217009  70.68963  71.98332  70.68963   NA
[14,] 218591  72.20682  74.36378  72.20682   NA
[15,] 237711  73.71524  74.46316  73.71524   NA
[16,] 232653  75.34195  75.51454  75.34195   NA
[17,] 255595  76.46221  81.70116  76.46221   NA
[18,] 257791  77.37070  78.35197  77.37070   NA
[19,] 249705  77.64845  74.36657  77.64845   NA
[20,] 245248  78.83179  70.48241  78.83179   NA
[21,] 243533  80.80679  71.00253  80.80679   NA
[22,] 251233  82.18598  73.73129  82.18598   NA
[23,] 241336  83.17191  70.69789  83.17191   NA
[24,] 268152  84.95746  76.36066  84.95746   NA
[25,] 307154  87.45263  84.56366  87.45263   NA
[26,] 299633  90.57314  81.66493  90.57314   NA
[27,] 303499  93.47729  82.25471  93.47729   NA
[28,] 346942  96.06590  95.73597  96.06590   NA
[29,] 380539  99.08321 106.44017  99.08321   NA
[30,] 341925  98.25567  92.87811  98.25567   NA
[31,] 372752 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   NA
[32,] 434661 102.85797 120.59851 102.85797   NA
[33,] 447301 104.57031 125.82197 104.57031   NA
[34,] 481151 105.87292 128.09005 105.87292   NA
[35,] 492012 107.46275 127.18914 107.46275   NA
[36,] 446731 107.26643 115.17443 107.26643   NA
[37,] 421469 108.05543        NA 108.05543   NA
[38,]     NA 109.89962        NA 109.89962   NA
[39,]     NA 111.50721        NA 111.50721   NA
[40,]     NA 113.60008        NA 113.60008   NA
[41,]     NA 116.10783        NA 116.10783   NA
[42,]     NA 118.68726        NA 118.68726   NA
[43,]     NA 121.31223        NA 121.31223   NA
[44,]     NA 123.97757        NA 123.97757   NA
[45,]     NA 126.64159        NA 126.64159   NA
[46,]     NA 129.30434        NA 129.30434   NA
[47,]     NA 131.99454        NA 131.99454   NA
[48,]     NA 134.74379        NA 134.74379   NA
[49,]     NA 137.63494        NA 137.63494   NA
[50,]     NA 140.66371        NA 140.66371   NA
[51,]     NA 143.76488        NA 143.76488   NA
[52,]     NA 146.95503        NA 146.95503   NA
[53,]     NA 150.22311        NA 150.22311   NA
[54,]     NA 153.55776        NA 153.55776   NA
[55,]     NA 156.97532        NA 156.97532   NA
[56,]     NA 160.46257        NA 160.46257   NA
[57,]     NA 164.05430        NA 164.05430   NA

$tab_uspgo05_id
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 26216  45.61025  62.42483  45.61025   NA
 [2,] 28524  49.70095  67.51353  49.70095   NA
 [3,] 29438  52.36556  70.45975  52.36556   NA
 [4,] 24650  54.18271  66.65260  54.18271   NA
 [5,] 28549  56.07181  66.45550  56.07181   NA
 [6,] 27288  57.55446  66.03600  57.55446   NA
 [7,] 25440  58.65441  62.34575  58.65441   NA
 [8,] 25024  60.36152  59.35909  60.36152   NA
 [9,] 25964  62.54470  56.06016  62.54470   NA
[10,] 26034  64.88341  55.74644  64.88341   NA
[11,] 28111  67.25120  55.81720  67.25120   NA
[12,] 28141  69.22237  55.54264  69.22237   NA
[13,] 26373  70.68963  54.46242  70.68963   NA
[14,] 24615  72.20682  50.81890  72.20682   NA
[15,] 26564  73.71524  50.64076  73.71524   NA
[16,] 25744  75.34195  51.75018  75.34195   NA
[17,] 26169  76.46221  50.24811  76.46221   NA
[18,] 28327  77.37070  49.02389  77.37070   NA
[19,] 28511  77.64845  49.17672  77.64845   NA
[20,] 24763  78.83179  48.20985  78.83179   NA
[21,] 24635  80.80679  49.03256  80.80679   NA
[22,] 26483  82.18598  50.64192  82.18598   NA
[23,] 25535  83.17191  52.70286  83.17191   NA
[24,] 25983  84.95746  53.26376  84.95746   NA
[25,] 29986  87.45263  57.50246  87.45263   NA
[26,] 37549  90.57314  66.43959  90.57314   NA
[27,] 44497  93.47729  71.23184  93.47729   NA
[28,] 48185  96.06590  74.85468  96.06590   NA
[29,] 56937  99.08321  88.50022  99.08321   NA
[30,] 55827  98.25567  93.07073  98.25567   NA
[31,] 59100 100.00000 100.00000 100.00000   NA
[32,] 71537 102.85797 109.18799 102.85797   NA
[33,] 68142 104.57031 108.66621 104.57031   NA
[34,] 61962 105.87292 104.11996 105.87292   NA
[35,] 61266 107.46275  99.98200 107.46275   NA
[36,] 51775 107.26643  97.63002 107.26643   NA
[37,] 32958 108.05543        NA 108.05543   NA
[38,]    NA 109.89962        NA 109.89962   NA
[39,]    NA 111.50721        NA 111.50721   NA
[40,]    NA 113.60008        NA 113.60008   NA
[41,]    NA 116.10783        NA 116.10783   NA
[42,]    NA 118.68726        NA 118.68726   NA
[43,]    NA 121.31223        NA 121.31223   NA
[44,]    NA 123.97757        NA 123.97757   NA
[45,]    NA 126.64159        NA 126.64159   NA
[46,]    NA 129.30434        NA 129.30434   NA
[47,]    NA 131.99454        NA 131.99454   NA
[48,]    NA 134.74379        NA 134.74379   NA
[49,]    NA 137.63494        NA 137.63494   NA
[50,]    NA 140.66371        NA 140.66371   NA
[51,]    NA 143.76488        NA 143.76488   NA
[52,]    NA 146.95503        NA 146.95503   NA
[53,]    NA 150.22311        NA 150.22311   NA
[54,]    NA 153.55776        NA 153.55776   NA
[55,]    NA 156.97532        NA 156.97532   NA
[56,]    NA 160.46257        NA 160.46257   NA
[57,]    NA 164.05430        NA 164.05430   NA
```

For every element in the list, I would like to compute the 5th column based on the following condition:
1. if element in first column 1 is less than or equal to 0.01 then element in column 5 is 100
2. otherwise element in column 5 is equal to column 2 * (column 3 / column 4)
this is the code I came up with and that doesnt work

```
fct_pgo <- function(x) {
  index <- pgo_computation[[x]][,1] > 0.01 & !is.na(pgo_computation[[x]][,1])
  pgo_computation <- within(pgo_computation, pgo_computation[[x]][,5][index] <- pgo_computation[[x]][,2][index]*(pgo_computation[[x]][,3][index]/pgo_computation[[x]][,4][index]))
  index1 <- pgo_computation[[x]][,1] <= 0.01 & !is.na(pgo_computation[[x]][,1])
  pgo_computation <- within(pgo_computation, pgo_computation[[x]][,5][index] <- 100)
}
lapply(1:length(pgo_computation),fct_pgo)
```

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution using good old `ifelse`

```
M[, 5] <- ifelse(M[, 1] <= 0.01, 
                 100, 
                 M[, 2] * M[, 3] / M[, 4])
```

Comment: @SamuelChampanhet  If this answers your question,  please upvote the answer and or accept is as the solution.  Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Based on PoGibas answer, this is the finalized code:

```
fct_pgo <- function(x) {
  pgo_computation[[x]][,5] <- ifelse(pgo_computation[[x]][,1] <=0.01,100,pgo_computation[[x]][,2]*(pgo_computation[[x]][,3]/pgo_computation[[x]][,4]))
}
##COMPUTE PGO SERIES
pgo_computation<-lapply(1:length(pgo_computation),fct_pgo)
```